# How to use react material-ui snackbar with existing button?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, snackbar

I followed the material UI snack bar for a simple snackbar example. But instead of having a separate button to display snackbar message I want the message to appear when my existing button is clicked.

SnackBarTest.tsx  --> ref [Reference Link](https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/)

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

export default function SnackBarTest() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (event: React.SyntheticEvent | React.MouseEvent, reason?: string) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Open simple snackbar</Button>
      <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        open={open}
        autoHideDuration={6000}
        onClose={handleClose}
        message="Note archived"
        action={
          <React.Fragment>
            <Button color="secondary" size="small" onClick={handleClose}>
              UNDO
            </Button>
            <IconButton size="small" aria-label="close" color="inherit" onClick={handleClose}>
              <CloseIcon fontSize="small" />
            </IconButton>
          </React.Fragment>
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now inside my sample.tsx file

```
import SnackBarTest from './SnackBarTest';

class Sample extends React.Component {
submitButton(){
  //doing some work
}


render(){
  return(
   <div>
     <Button onClick={this.submitButton}>Submit<Button/>
     <SnackBarTest />
   </div>

  )
}
```

Inside my sample.tsx It will show my existing button and second button for the snack bar. How am I able to move the SnackBarTest button functionality into my existing Button?

Comment: pass a prop from parent to snackbartest component. or hold the state from redux store, and consider that as a source of truth.

Comment: @hashbytes Can you share a brief example on how to do so?